# actionoverflow button changes toolbar background in the corner

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I need some help. I used a toolbar by replacing action bar. The problem is when i include the action overflow button it doesn't come over the toolbar instead it changes the background of that specific area in the toolbar where the overflow button is. How can i keep the same background with action overflow button included? Searched a lot but nothing worked. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. Here is my code

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#FBBB1C"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FBBB1C"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>


<style name="DayTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/DayEditText</item>
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/DayListView</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/DayAlertStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="DayEditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>


<style name="DayListView" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>

</style>

<style name="DayAlertStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/TitleDialogTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.stationcars.hv.LoginScreen">

<item android:id="@+id/algo"
    android:title=""
    android:icon="@drawable/menu48"
    app:showAsAction="always">

    <menu>

        <item android:id="@+id/action_day"
            android:title="@string/action_daytheme"
            android:icon="@drawable/daytheme"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item android:id="@+id/action_night"
            android:title="@string/action_nighttheme"
            android:icon="@drawable/nighttheme"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item android:id="@+id/action_version"
            android:title="@string/action_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/alertinfo"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item android:id="@+id/action_kiosk"
            android:title="@string/action_kiosk"
            android:icon="@drawable/toggle"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

    </menu>

</item>

    </menu>
```

With overflow button, background is cut and without overflow button background is complete in the toolbar.